# Boolean on a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hey guys not sure if what I am trying to do is possible but I want to make a new column in a dataframe based on whether the string says 'complete'. if it does i want the new column row to say 1 if not 0. Since I have many records i put it in a loop.

```
august_report['Lease'] = np.nan
for x in august_report.iterrows():
    if august_report['Transaction Types'] =='Matched Lease transaction':
        august_report['Lease'] = '1'
    else:
        august_report['Lease'] = '0'
```

Comment: where's the word complete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Numpy` provides an easy way to do this if you have two values like your example (using `np.where`).  If you have multiple cases, look at `np.select`.

```
import numpy as np
august_report['Lease'] = np.where(august_report['Transaction Types'] =='Matched Lease transaction', '1','0')
```

Comment: Could I also use this with a numerical conditional such as ">0"? btw what you said worked great, really appreciate your help!

Comment: Yeah you can... and your output values can be strings as currently written, boolean, integers (1,0), etc.  If this is the answer you were looking for, do you mind accepting the answer with the check mark?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can assign values to a column like:

```
august_report['Lease'] = august_report['Transaction Types'].eq('Matched Lease transaction').astype(int)
```

Probably a numerical `0` and `1` are better here (or even `False` and `True`, by dropping the `.astype(int)`), since that shows that we are dealing with numerical data, not text data.

Answer (score 0):

can apply a lambda

```
df['Lease'] = df['Transaction Types'].apply(lambda x: '1' if x == 'Matched Lease transaction' else '0')
```